# error: no match for ‘operator>>’

Tags: c++

I was just trying an example on exception handling.
I am getting the error  error: no match for ‘operator>>’
What is wrong in my program.
I am using linux gcc.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void div(double, double);
void read (double *, double *);
main()
{
    double a,b;
    cout<<"enter the two nos";
    cin>>a>>b;
    read(&a,&b);
    div(a,b);
}

void div(double a, double b)
{
    double d;
    try {
        if(b==0)
        throw "divide by zero condition occured";
        d=a/b;
        cout<<"divsion of two no is"<<d<<endl;
    }catch(const char *e)
    {
        cout<<"exception is "<<e<<endl;
    }
}
void read(double *a,double *b)
{
    cout<<"Enter the 2 no.";
    cin>>a>>b;
}
```

I also tried another function for read function

```
void read(double *a,double *b)
{
    double c,d;
    cout<<"Enter the 2 no.";
    cin>>c>>d;
    a=c;
    b=d;
}
```

but it also has the error:

> cannot convert ‘double’ to ‘double*’ in assignment

Comment: You might want to include the complete error message in your question.

Comment: Typo.  You need to dereference `a` and `b` in `read`.

Comment: Pass by reference.  It will eliminate these pointer defects.

Comment: In the main method, the call to read is redundant "cin>>a>>b;  read(&a,&b);" remove the call to read.

Comment: Your program is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void read(double *a,double *b)
{
    double c,d;
    cout<<"Enter the 2 no.";
    cin>>c>>d;
    a=c;
    b=d;
}
```

This won't work, because you want to change the values pointed to by the pointers, not the pointer itself, result in the error. Fix it to this:

```
void read(double *a,double *b)
{
    double c,d;
    cout<<"Enter the 2 no.";
    cin>>c>>d;
    *a=c;
    *b=d;
}
```

Of course, in such a case, I wouldn't recommend using pointers, better to use references, so no dereferencing is required, and you can call it like `read(a,b)`:

```
void read(double &a,double &b)
{
    double c,d;
    cout<<"Enter the 2 no.";
    cin>>c>>d;
    a=c;
    b=d;
}
```

The `double& b` notation means pass-by-reference. You also have the same problem for your other read function, fix it to this:

```
void read(double *a,double *b)
{
    cout<<"Enter the 2 no.";
    cin>>*a>>*b;
}
```

or better:

```
void read(double &a,double &b)
{
    cout<<"Enter the 2 no.";
    cin>>a>>b;
}
```

Comment: The temporaries are redundant; I don't know why you're suggesting them.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `a` is a *pointer* to a `double`.
The variable `c` is a `double`.
The expression `a = c;` is assigning a `double` to a *pointer* to `double`.

Try:  `*a = c;`

Answer (score 1):

```
void read(double *a,double *b)
{
    cout<<"Enter the 2 no.";
    cin>>a>>b;
}
```

change this to

```
void read(double *a,double *b)
{
    cout<<"Enter the 2 no.";
    cin>>*a>>*b; 
}
```

because the object `cin` has a method called `operator>>` which is overloaded to take different types of data to work upon. Like `operator>>(short& __n)` to take input for `short` data type, `operator>>(float& __f)` to take input for `float` data type. But no overloaded version of the method takes `double*` as argument. and in the code `a` and `b` are `double*`.
So De-referencing `a` and `b` returns `double` and there is a overloaded version of `operator>>` which takes `double` as argument that is `operator>>(double& __f)`. So, changing `cin>>a>>b` to `cin>>*a>>*b` will work as intended.

Comment: Understood @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign to the value at the pointer:

```
*a=c;
*b=d;
```